# Unable to hide TabLayout when scrolling (HELP!)

Tags: java, android, scroll, hide, android-tablayout

I can't get any way to hide the TabLayout when I scroll a fragment

I tried app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" but no results

I put appbarlayout, collapsedBarLayout too but not hide anything

Right now I have this code:

```
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    >
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/tab"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      />
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/subtab"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
      />
  </LinearLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

      android:id="@+id/viewpagertabb"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_background"
      app:tabMode="scrollable"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_background_selected"

      />

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

      android:id="@+id/viewpagertabsub"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:background="@drawable/sub_tab_layout_background"
      app:tabMode="scrollable"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      app:tabBackground="@drawable/sub_tab_layout_selector"
      app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blanco"
      android:layout_below="@id/viewpagertabb"

      />

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/viewpagerpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/viewpagertabsub"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the last FrameLayout is where is the content of a fragment. Anyone?

Thank to all!